# "DBSession link()" method not exist in latest SDK of Dropbox

Tags: ios, objective-c, dropbox-api

I have replaced latest dropbox SDK in my project. 
i found that **link() method is not exist in DBSession.h** file.

```
 [[DBSession sharedSession] link];
```

is there any other method for link dropbox?
if any one know about this ps help me.

**Update:**
I found **[DBSession sharedSession] linkFromController** method.
I have used this function instead of link method and its working well..

Answer (score 0):

I found **[DBSession sharedSession] linkFromController method.**
I have used this function instead of link method and its working well..